# How to cast abstract class to non-abstract class?

Tags: typescript, abstract-class

If I have an `abstract class Adapter {}`, I'd like to create a function which accepts a non-abstract constructor extending this class and returns a new instance of the class.

e.g.

```js
export abstract class Adapter {}

export function change(adapterConstructor: typeof Adapter) {
  return new adapterConstructor();
}
```

Unfortunately, this example doesn't work because the typescript compiler correctly complains that an abstract class cannot be instantiated.

Is it possible to limit the `adapterConstructor` argument to only non-abstract implementations of `typeof Adapter`?

i.e. something like

```js
export abstract class Adapter {}

export function change(adapterConstructor: NonAbstract<typeof Adapter>) {
  return new adapterConstructor();
}
```

At the moment, my solution is to simply make the `Adapter` class non-abstract and have all of the methods which *should* be abstract throw errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can require the `change()` method to take an intersection of `typeof Adapter` (which is not known to be newable) with a constructor signature.  (EDIT for TS4.2+: the type `typeof Adapter` is now known to have an [`abstract` construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#abstract-construct-signatures), so you can't leave it in there.  Instead, you can use `Pick<typeof Adapter, keyof typeof Adapter>` which keeps any static properties but discards any call/construct signature entirely).

First, I'm going to give `Adapter` some structure, since [empty classes behave strangely in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) and we don't want that to trip us up.  Also I want to add a static method to `Adapter` so that you can convince yourself that `change()` will be able to call it:

```
export abstract class Adapter {
  prop = "adapterProp";
  static staticMethod() {
    console.log("HI THERE");
  }
}
```

So here's the `change()` signature:

```
export function change(
  adapterConstructor: Pick<typeof Adapter, keyof typeof Adapter> & (new () => Adapter)
) {
  adapterConstructor.staticMethod();
  return new adapterConstructor();
}
```

You can see that `adapterConstructor` is both newable and has `Adapter`'s static method.  Do note that the constructor signature is `new () => Adapter`, meaning it needs no arguments and produces an `Adapter`.

Let's make sure this behaves as you want:

```
const cannotConstructAbstract = new Adapter(); // error!
change(Adapter); // error! cannot assign abstract to non-abstract
```

You can't `new` the `Adapter` class, and you can't call `change(Adapter)`, as desired.

Now let's make a concrete subclass:

```
class ChickenAdapter extends Adapter {
  cluck() {
    console.log("B'KAW!");
  }
}
    
const canConstruct = new ChickenAdapter(); // okay
const chickenAdapter = change(ChickenAdapter); // okay
```

You *can* `new` the `ChickenAdapter` class, and so you can call `change(ChickenAdapter)`, which returns an `Adapter`:

```
chickenAdapter.prop // okay
chickenAdapter.cluck(); // error! it only returns an Adapter, not a ChickenAdapter
```

Note that `chickenAdapter` is not known to be an `ChickenAdapter` instance, since `change()` returns an `Adapter`.  If you want `change()` to keep track of this, you can make it generic in the return type:

```
export function change<T extends Adapter>(
  adapterConstructor: typeof Adapter & (new () => T)
) {
  adapterConstructor.staticMethod();
  return new adapterConstructor();
}
```

And then `chickenAdapter.cluck()` works:

```
chickenAdapter.cluck(); // okay
```

Let's move on to some edge cases:

```
class CowAdapter extends Adapter {
  constructor(public color: string) {
    super();
  }

  moo() {
    console.log("MRRROOOORM!");
  }
}

const howNow = new CowAdapter("brown");
const butNeedsAnArgument = new CowAdapter(); // error! expected 1 argument
change(CowAdapter); // error!  CowAdapter needs arguments
```

Here, `change()` does not accept `CowAdapter` because that class requires a constructor argument, which the body of `change()` does not pass in.  That's probably the right thing to do.

And also, let's make sure that you can't pass in something whose static side looks okay but doesn't produce an `Adapter`:

```
class NotAnAdapter {
  static staticMethod() {}
  notAnAdapter = true;
}

change(NotAnAdapter); // error!
//Property 'prop' is missing in type 'NotAnAdapter' but required in type 'Adapter'.
```

Also looks good.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=23&pln=10&pc=65#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwEYGcZQQY3pgNglFOAQQBMEwZgo4BvAWACg44B6VuACxhjBQC52AcwCWMTgFckAOkwQAtqwCyIzFAgoIAMxisAKgE8wwAMpqRlVgHcRAaxGsAYsQCKAYiucDAWlIRv4sAowN7A8pQ+eATBKN5IwJwIAG4haBgAdkLAuAZMLGDqYHAAvHAARGERcFGEQXDyCLbAcHomcKTASUSVMAZwQvi1RIB8G4DCu2UA3HlwaAgwqjMwc6pKwOIQpAAUAJR00yxy6Zq4wNK4EEKbZQASAJIt1wCiAEqPZdtTzHAAvky-jExQJBYHAtBJ0tgRBB0tVEplgAAePRwUBUdKkIhkChUKAAPk20wQ5Eo1AAwtC0hJsNB+HAAAqqWwI3rGbQkYk4gA0cCaBjZLOAbKxJLxcAAZHBNulgFZJbtiriWtsmLsGF8idiyRT0FSYNBpLN5phVusth9plA1hIoDDpbKNSLyUcddSoDtPv8mIc0NUEOl0hAYE7KdhiKh0Fh4KU7ezNW6PmwONR1FAAIReuFZTbCnEJ9goqAp1O+-2BxCEERCGHINKRuB6uAB9LeGsR7BML2DIikziM4DpHPUFEgNEY2MivZfPBU2w7ScsA4UiAnM4XK4AIQA5ABpYgAdVT70+LH+-29OD9wZdUcbMrgPb7A451HdibgEFsCFyjHPsMfg5oUpMEzYBNgfTAmifOM8w4D8vwzf9nygaQCggMAJjfODv2AxC41kXAZ1ffMsI7H8u3vCArAA4dR0xJD52qbUoF1aBNjAKRcAWORzigWk0hETJVX2GYJGMeNjx+UiWHkCAIDnNUF0Yo5l1Oc5LjKJRni0gB5XTtOeJRD3NL5T1I39OEogA5SiSlvWVySopCriQdQrHSI8vW1OAkAkGBLOAYAMWIAcoCECR5H7G8YwcgCiKTQtoGLIFgGwQK4AARkQULwsijM-SzGKkJggsixYQq41vQKiAQbKIvSGAUDM8jrJgYLqIUxZlkwTqjRNCyzToSSvgDVqoInUodWAD0zJAzYWraoqMPzZNEqYdg6UKahejgTdULATc4BEIh5COlABKEQ6YQFHb5rGnEDp8+BLQARwkERLVIS76yMZpNwAzdpCYIA)

Comment: Thank you! I had actually previously tried `typeof Adapter & (new () => Adapter)` and had received a "'DateAdapter' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'DateAdapter'" error which I couldn't shake. Your response made me try things over again. Turns out the *real* problem was the type should be `typeof Adapter & (new (...args: any[]) => Adapter)`, which works as expected.

Comment: Sure, as long as you don't call `new ctor()` with no arguments in the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could go dynamic, but at the risk of allowing `Adapter` itself to be passed in, which kinda defeats the purpose of an abstract class...

```
export abstract class Adapter {}

export function change(adapterConstructor: typeof Adapter): Adapter {
    const constr: any = adapterConstructor;
    return new constr() as Adapter;
}
```

Otherwise, you'd need to introduce a concrete base class to use in place of Adapter... or change Adapter to be an interface that the each class would have to implement rather than using the abstract class.

Comment: Ya, this is what I was afraid of. At the moment I think my solution of making `Adapter` non-abstract is the better work around (for my use case), as it also allows for use of `InstanceType` which can't normally be used on abstract classes. I'll leave this question open for the time being, but if a better response doesn't come in I'll mark your answer as correct.  Thanks for the information!